# How to draw lines touching x and y axes

Tags: plotting, formatting

I have a simple code to generate a plot

```
 ListPlot[Table[4.5 (x - 5) + RandomReal[{-20, 20}], {x, 5, 100, 10}]]
```

I would like each point to have two red lines intersecting the x and y axes along with a label that gives the ratio=y/x for each point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
tbl = Table[{x, 4.5 (x - 5) + RandomReal[{-20, 20}]}, {x, 5, 100, 10}];
Show[ListPlot[tbl], 
  Graphics[{Red, 
    Map[{x = #[[1]]; y = #[[2]];
      Line[{{0, y}, {x, y}, {x, 0}}], 
      Text[ToString[y/x], {x, y}, {0, -1}]} &, tbl]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: There is a lot going on in that. Study the details. Look up each of those functions in the help system. Try little changes. See how much you can learn from that so you will be able to use some of those ideas for your next problem. You are trying to learn how to think in a way that you will likely guess how to write things that look like this and work like this

Answer (score 1):

```
xs = Range[5, 100, 10]
idxs = Range@Length@xs
ys = Table[4.5 (x - 5) + RandomReal[{-20, 20}], {x, xs}]
labels = ys/xs
vlines = InfiniteLine[{{#1, 0}, {#1, 1}}] & /@ idxs
hlines = InfiniteLine[{{0, #}, {1, #}}] & /@ ys
ListPlot[ys -> labels,
 Prolog -> {LightRed, vlines, hlines}]
```

[image]

It probably looks better framed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or like the following:

```
pnts = Table[{x, 4.5 (x - 5) + RandomReal[{-20, 20}]}, {x, 5, 100, 10}];
lines = Line[{{0, Last[#]}, #, {First[#], 0}}] & /@ pnts;
slopes = Text["m = dy/dx = " <> ToString@N[Divide@@Reverse[#]], #*{0.5, 1}, {0, -1}] & /@ pnts;

Show[Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point/@pnts, Red, lines, Blue, slopes}],
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 500}}, AspectRatio -> 1 
 ]
```